# Why javascript error: "Child is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why I cannot instantiate Child inside ChildModel : "Uncaught TypeError: Child is not a function"

https://jsfiddle.net/zvabqj0m/

```
var Child = (function() {
  function Child(data) {
    alert("Child");
  }

  return Child();
})();

var ChildModel = (function() {
  function ChildModel(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.child = new Child(data);
    alert("ChildModel");
  }

  return ChildModel();
})();

data = "hello";
var childModel = new ChildModel(data);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because, in the called closure, you `return Child();` instead of simply `return Child;`.

By doing so, you are actually assigning to the "outer" `Child` the return value of the inner one, that is, `undefined`, since it returns nothing.